# Share data by reference between subviews SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

In my ContentView I have two subviews, a HeaderView and a SettingsView. Whenever exiting the settings (which is a .sheet()) I need to load data in my HeaderView. Since the header has a timer I thought about checking a boolean value that gets toggled when exiting the setting.
To do so I create a Binding variable in the ContentView that I share among the subviews.
The header has a viewModel which also gets this variable by reference (using inout) when the timer publishes.

The code :

```
struct ContentView: View {
@AppStorage("showSettings") var showSettings: Bool = true
@State var settingsHaveChanged = false

var body: some View {
     VStack {
         Button("Settings") {
               showSettings = true
         }
         
         HeaderView(settingsHaveChanged: $settingsHaveChanged)
     }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSettings) {
        SettingsView(showSettings: $showSettings, settingsHaveChanged: $settingsHaveChanged)
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {

@Binding var showSettings: Bool
@Binding var settingsHaveChanged: Bool

var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
        .toolbar {
            Button("Done") {
               showSettings = false
               settingsHaveChanged = true
            }
        } 
    }
}

struct HeaderView: View {
@StateObject var headerViewModel: HeaderViewModel = HeaderViewModel()
@Binding var settingsHaveChanged: Bool

var body: some View {
    Text("Header")
    .onReceive(headerViewModel.timer, perform: { _ in
        headerViewModel.updateTimeRemaining(while: &settingsHaveChanged)
        })
    }
}

class HeaderViewModel: ObservableObject {

func updateTimeRemaining(while settingsHaveChanged: inout Bool) {
    if settingsHaveChanged {
        //load data
        settingsHaveChanged = false
        }
    //compute data
    }
}
```

Are their other ways of sharing data by reference between subviews, namely how to trigger a function call inside another subview's view model within a first subview

Comment: ViewModels should never know about each other. you can post notifications and have different views or objects subscribe to them

Comment: Have a look at this  **official** link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)
 In essence, declare `@StateObject var headerViewModel: HeaderViewModel = HeaderViewModel()`  higher in your view hierarchy (ContentView) and pass the model to the subviews, using for example
 `@EnvironmentObject var headerViewModel: HeaderViewModel`

Comment: SwiftUI is designed to work with values not references so you'll have trouble doing this. The reason it uses values is to prevent inconsistencies typical of shared mutable state in references.